# SQL assign value to variable from multiple Select results

Tags: sql

I have a question about how SQL assigns a value to a variable if the Select statement returns multiple results.
For example if the following Select statement returns 5 rows, which one is assigned to the variable.

```
declare @i int
SELECT @i = age
  FROM student
```

Comment: sounds pretty darned easy to test...

Comment: What's the database? The behavior can vary depending on the engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you will end up with the last value returned when the statement is finished. Without a proper ORDER BY your results can be random because it depends on the last record returned.

You can also use += to get a cumulative value.

Below example works in SQL Server.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Student
CREATE TABLE #Student
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1)
    , Age INT
)

INSERT INTO #Student VALUES
(20), (21), (30), (26), (50)

DECLARE @i INT

/*  Update with each record returned  */
SELECT @i = Age
FROM #Student AS S
ORDER BY S.Age

SELECT @i AS SingleValue

/*  Cumulative value  */
SET @i = 0

SELECT @i += Age
FROM #Student AS S
ORDER BY S.Age

SELECT @i AS CumulativeValue
```

Answer (score 1):

Above, youll get the last value as result since for many records that `i` will get updated each time

In short, Thats when you can make use of `CURSOR` when Sql query returns multiple results or you could also make use of `ARRAY` for storing multiple homogeneous objects or `RECORD` for storing multiple heterogeneous objects in Pl/sql